# remove margin when expanding accordion Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to remove the margin froman accordion as in this example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxrbxnbpava?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts),  but I have no idea how to use `MatAccordionDisplayMode = 'flat'` to remove the margin.

Comment: Have you seen the solution I provide for your issue ? If it doesnt work feel free to tell me

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

You don't need to modify the CSS. Add `displayMode` to the mat-accordion element.

```html
<mat-accordion displayMode="flat">
...
</mat-accordion>
```

Longer answer:

According to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) for MatAccordion

> @Input()
> displayMode: MatAccordionDisplayMode
>
> Display mode used for all expansion panels in the accordion. Currently two display modes exist: default - a gutter-like spacing is placed around any expanded panel, placing the expanded panel at a different elevation from the rest of the accordion. flat - no spacing is placed around expanded panels, showing all panels at the same elevation.

As you have discovered, by default the accordion elevates and separates the opened panel from its siblings. You have to add a `displayMode` attribute to the accordion in order to affect this.

Much easier than modifying the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you want your two panels to be glued together without any margin between them.

To do so, add this in your **component.css**

```
.mat-expansion-panel-spacing{
  margin:0;
}

.mat-expansion-panel:not(:last-child){
  border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}
```

Here is the result

[image]

Also, by adding `border-bottom-right/left-radius:0px;` for `.mat-expansion-panel:not(:last-child)`, you remove the border radius that can be awful if the accordion panels are sticked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the margin in the left of Age text box?

[image]

If so, you can simply make the `margin-left` as zero.

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-left: 0">
  <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="number" min="1">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: HI, NO, I mean the margin added when it "floats" the mat-expansion-panel. I